# How to use $_FILES to store a BLOB Windows Azure

Tags: php, windows, file, azure, blob

I am using windows azure blob storage service to store data. My php file is this

```
<?php

    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;
    use WindowsAzure\Blob\Models\CreateContainerOptions;
    use WindowsAzure\Blob\Models\PublicAccessType;
    use WindowsAzure\Common\ServiceException;

    // Create blob REST proxy.
    $connectionString = "[CONNECTION STRING (WORKS)]";
    $blobRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connectionString);


    $blob_name = "myblob";
    // Create blob REST proxy.


    try {
        //Upload blob
        $blobRestProxy->createBlockBlob("containerName",$blob_name, $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
        echo '104';
    }
    catch(ServiceException $e){
        // Handle exception based on error codes and messages.
        // Error codes and messages are here:
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179439.aspx
        $code = $e->getCode();
        $error_message = $e->getMessage();
        echo $code.": ".$error_message."<br />";
    }

?>
```

The BLOB is created perfectly...
The only problem i'm having is when I use $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] it actually stores in the BLOB the PATH of the file, not the contents of the file itself.

My question is, how can I store a BLOB using the $_FILES contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the contents of the file using `file_get_contents()` or other method:

```
$blob_content = file_get_contents($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
$blobRestProxy->createBlockBlob("containerName", $blob_name, $blob_content);
```

MS actually attempts to give an example [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-php-how-to-use-blobs/#UploadBlob), however `fopen()` doesn't work like that.